# Langchain | Qdrant | TimeOutError: The write operation timeout

Tags: python, openai-api, langchain, openaiembeddings, qdrant

```
embeddings = OpenAIEmbeddings(openai_api_key=settings.OPENAI_API_KEY,headers=headers)
db = Qdrant.from_documents(
    documents=documents, 
    embedding=embeddings, 
    collection_name=collection_name, 
    url=settings.QDRANT_CONNECTION_STRING, 
    force_recreate=False, 
)
db.add_documents(documents)

OUTPUT ERROR:
TimeoutError: The write operation timed out
```

`your text`
In this above code, I am adding the document with embeddings in a quadrant vector storage. I have set up a project and in which, the documents upload from the front end and at the backend, it creates embeddings and add documents.

document size - 50KB < 1MB < 10 MB < 100 MB
time to upload documents - 5 seconds < 30 seconds < 5 minutes < 10 minutes.

The timeout error occurs on random file size and on random timeframe.

If anyone is facing an issue or have any solutions please let me know.

Python Libraries.
langchain==0.0.350
qdrant-client==1.7.0